# ¿Qué significa que un sistema operativo se quede sin soporte?

Tags: linux, red-hat

Un proveedor de internet me ofrece un servicio de virtualización cloud (modelo IaaS),
Sin embargo, dentro de los sistemas operativos que ofrece cuenta con red hat 4 y 5, pero tengo entendido que ya no cuentan con soporte, como o en que me puede afectar esto?

Comment: Generalmente significa que el fabricante ya no va a sacar actualizaciones (ni de casos críticos de seguridad) para esa versión del sistema operativo. También, en caso de problemas, no puedes acudir al soporte del fabricante por ayuda, pues ya no te la van a ofrecer.  En otras palabras, si es para jugar, instalalo, nada pasa. Si es para producción de algo serio, ni de broma los uses, estás metiéndote o probablemente metiendo a alguien más en problemas futuros, sobre todo en estos dorados tiempos.

Comment: Habrá quien te diga que no importa, pero no será nadie que lleve con responsabilidad, sobre sus hombros, el peso de la infraestructura de una empresa seria.

Comment: Porqué metiendo a alguien más en problemas?, es que me están pidiendo  montar un servidor CRM en este sistema.

Comment: Entiendo entonces que como ya no tendrá actualizaciones de seguridad, es fácil que puedan atacar mi información?

Comment: No necesariamente fácil, ni seguro, pero entre más pase el tiempo, será más probable que lo hagan, pues siempre aparecerá algún componente con alguna vulnerabilidad que comenzará a ser explotada por alguien. Es una de las razones por las que se recomienda mantener al día los sistemas operativos de los servidores.

Comment: Existe alguna manera de minimizar esto, es decir algún programa que me ayude a no dejarlo tan vulnerable?, por otro lado si eligiese en lugar de redhat a windows 2008 sería lo mismo, ya  que igualmente se ha quedado si soporte,no?

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres usar versiones tan viejas?

Comment: Porque son las que me ofrece tal proveedor de internet en sus servidores virtuales

Comment: No parece el proveedor más actualizado del mundo. Como sea, creo que es preferible que instales todo, si no te ofrece un pre-instalado, que quedarte con una opción tan mala. También puedes cambiar de proveedor, al menos, para este servidor.

Comment: En pocas palabras un servidor en cualquiera de estos sistemas es una mala idea? :(

Comment: Como te dije antes, yo no lo haría (ni de broma) para un servidor de producción, igual encontrarás quién te diga que no hay problema.